# Getting KeyError message in python function

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop

I'm getting keyerror message when running the code

```
def newTopo(info):
        G = []
        for stat in info["network-topology"]["topology"]:
                for link in stat["link"]:
                        if "host" not in link["link-id"]:
```

keyerror below

```
 for link in stat["link"]:
KeyError: 'link'
```

Please find the source where I extract the data above
[image: source info]

Structure of the source info

```
- <network-topology xmlns="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:network-topology">
  + <topology>...</topology>
  - <topology>
    + <node>...</node>
    + <node>...</node>
    - <link>
        <link-id>host:00:00:00:00:00:01/openflow:1:1</link-id>
        + <destination>...</destination>
        + <source>...</source>
        </link>
    + <link>
    </topology>
```

The 'link' is exist...but why getting error... please help and advise...thanks

Comment: just `for link in stat:` not `for link in stat['link']:` as the latter is saying find link in stat try and find link again...

Comment: When i remove ['link'] and run again I'm getting another error ---> if "host" not in link["link-id"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: the next line is implying link is either a dict or a list? that is not correct or maybe you're code is lacking some substance, so right now, it's either a key or a string in stat and not in `link["link_id"]:` you have to fix the next line as well.

Comment: I change for test instead of link i replace it with node... and code can run without keyerror... I miss somewhere....i have no idea for now...

Comment: node and link on the same data structure (under 'topology')...for link in stat["node"]: no keyerror....

Comment: Did you try to replace `stat['link']` by `stat.get('link')` ? To avoid KeyError?